# Python. slice a part of the string that begins with a specific character and end with a character

Tags: python, string

I want to extract information after a chosen character and stop before a chosen character; for example, extract from `*` and end with a space, then put the identified words into a new list.

```
>>> extract_star('*we are *engineers *happy very *much')
['we', 'engineers', 'happy', 'much']
```

I tried using `split` and `find` functions, or maybe check boolean type with `startswith` and `endswith` functions ... but it didn't really work..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for that:

```
import re

def extract_star(s):
    return re.findall(r'\*(.+?)\b', s)

extract_star('*we are *engineers *happy very *much')
# ['we', 'engineers', 'happy', 'much']
```

This collects all `.+?` groups (one or more of anything non-greedily) preceded by a `'*'` and followed by a word boundary `'\b'` (with space you'd miss the last match).

Answer (score 1):

It appears the you're close with the methods you know:

- Split the string on spaces
- Find the elements that start with `*`
- Keep the remainders of those elements

  extract_star(s):
      words = s.split()
      star_words = [word for word in words if word.startswith('*')]
      result = [word[1:] for word in star_words
      return result

... or, in one expression ...

```
return [word[1:] for word in s.split() if word.startswith('*')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by `'*'`, ignore empty strings, split by whitespace, then extract the 0th value:

```
def extract_star(x):
    return [i.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for i in x.split('*') if i]

res = extract_star('*we are *engineers *happy very *much')

['we', 'engineers', 'happy', 'much']
```

Or functionally:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def extract_star(x):
    return list(map(itemgetter(0), map(str.split, filter(None, x.split('*')))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The rest have given plenty of options for how you can do this if it starts with the character.

If it doesn't *start* with the special character (or even if it does), you can try doing something like this.

```
def extract_star(sentence, sc = '*'):
    mywords = sentence.split()
    res = [word[:word.find(sc)] + word[word.find(sc) + 1:] for word in mywords if sc in word]
    return res

result = extract_star('*we are *engineers *happy very *much')
result = extract_star('*we are *engineers *happy very m*uch')

['we', 'engineers', 'happy', 'much']
```